# Using Jquery to create a drag and drop select box or text box? (not lists)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I've worked thru the various jquery UI demos of drag and drop and sortable. These show how to get items from one list to another. One example even shows a shopping cart demo.

Am I missing something in that a

item won't be part of a post to the server right? so what use is this other than reorganizing a display on a page?

Is it possible to adapt this to some sort of input field?

TIA
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> item won't be part of a post to the server right? so what use is this
>   other than reorganizing a display on a page?

Allowing users to reorganize the elements in the page is a nice feature, even if you aren't notified on the server. For example, by allowing users to drag and drop elements, you may store his current page layout in `localStorage` so that the next time the user visits your page, the layout is restored automatically. You don't need to be notified on the server side what the user preferences are.

All of these jQuery plugins (sortable, draggable, etc.) have functions that you can hook into and trigger some server side processing as well. For example, when a user drags and drops an element from one section of the screen to another, you can perfectly make an ajax request and do some processing on your end. This would provide a very nice user experience to the user.

For example:

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
       $.post('http://server/somection',data{...});//do something on the server-side
    };
});
```

Absolutely! [jsfiddle with demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jrh9N/)

Comment: How about being able to drag an item from a list to a text box? Is something like that possible?

Comment: After working your example from the jsfiddle site into a test page I was able to drag an item into the text box and the text box display showed the text of the dragged item but when I submitted the form the field was null.  Not sure what is going on. I will continue digging into it but am open to ideas.

Comment: It's null probably because the `input` element doesn't have a `name` attribute (at least I didn't give it a name on my example). Remember: only input elements with a `name` attribute are submitted in the request. change it to `<input id="someid" name="someid" />` and you'll see that you will be able to read it on the server side.

Comment: I should have caught that too.  Thanks!  My next step is to figure out how to make it work with multiple selections.